# Which household electronics contain or used to contain photo multiplier tubes?

Tags: multiplier

I would like to get my hands on one, but I am unsure where to find them (other than online). Are there any old household electronics that have them, used to have them? I am willing to go scavenge hunting for some.

Comment: Not unless your household is like the one with the big cellar in "Silence of the Lambs"...

Comment: Not exactly household but you can sometimes find used or scrap components from scanning electron microscopes, which use PMTs as part of the SE detectors.

Comment: You can get reasonably close with a SPAD (Single Photon Avalanche Detector). ST makes a ToF (Time of Flight) sensor, the [VL6180](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/12784), which has one built-in. Not exactly sure how you'd go about interfacing it though...

Answer (score 6):

Sure, if you happen to have a [1955 Lincoln](http://ricebrosplymouth.com/NSD/10763.pdf) Continental with all the options kicking around.. they were used in the automatic headlight dimmer circuit.

> OPERATION: With headlights turned on, and the pilot
>   light indicating automatic control, light striking the
>   photo-multiplier tube of the control assembly causes
>   generation of a weak electrical current. This current
>   is electronically amplified and used to actuate relays
>   in the switch assembly

Otherwise, I think you'll find them very, very rare on the ground.

Comment: I'm just wondering why you happen to know this and have that technical note handy.

Comment: @VladimirCravero LOL, good question. I happen to remember this from reading a then-old Popular Mechanics (I think) as a kid.

Answer (score 3):

No, there are no household electronics that would include a photomultiplier tube.  They are expensive, they work at high voltages, and may need to be cooled to low temps.  Depending on what they are used for, they may need large amplification good to very high frequency.  These hefty obstacles preclude their use in consumer grade products.

Comment: They are also relatively fragile for consumer electronics, which is another obstacle.  Also, can you think of a consumer application which would require single-photon counting?

Comment: @NickAlexeev I can think of quite a few consumer products that *might* exist if there were convenient and inexpensive single photon (or even tens of photons) detectors available.  Picture, for example, being able to immediately tell if your water were safe to drink.

Answer (score 1):

Only thing I can think of is night vision equipment, which isn't exactly household but may be available from military surplus.

Comment: Image intensifier != photomultiplier.

Comment: Image intensifier tube is different from photomultiplier tube (PMT).  Image intensifier receives photons and outputs visible light.  Photomultiplier tube receives photons and outputs electric current.  By the way, where I live, it's easier to find a PMT tube in surplus bio-medical and bio-analytical equipment than in military equipment.

Answer (score 0):

A film drum scanner might use a photomultiplier tube. Not all that easy to find one in a junkyard though.

[This page](http://www.fineprintimaging.com/about/tips/scanning.htm) touches on them.

Any PMT will have a complex high voltage power supply, be sure to salvage that too.